# SwiftUI: "Property initializers run before 'self' is available" in @AppStorage use

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, properties, picker

I am new to Swift and want to solve this. I want, that the currency from the picker is saved when I close and come back into the app. (via @AppStorage) But I can't use anything I have in mind to define the $currency to $cur in @AppStorage. Thanks for your help! Here the code:

```
//Settings
struct SettingsView: View {

@State private var currency = "$"
var currencies = ["$", "€", "¥", "£"]
@AppStorage("name") var name = ""
@AppStorage("cur") var cur = "\($currency)"
//Cannot use instance member '$currency' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Your name")) {
                TextField("Tim", text: $name)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Your currency")) {
                Picker(selection: $currency, label: Text("Your Currency")) {
                    ForEach(currencies, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
        }
        
    }
    .navigationTitle("Settings")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to `$currency` when you define `cur`. This is a limitation of Swift. It obvious to you that currency has a value already, but Swift won't let you use it until after the initializer is done setting up self.  This has nothing to do with AppStorage -- it's a rule that property initializers cannot refer to other (non-static) properties.

So, this

```
@State private var currency = "$"
@AppStorage("cur") var cur = "\($currency)"
```

Could be

```
@State private var currency = "$"
@AppStorage("cur") var cur = "$" // set it to the same value
```

or

```
private static let dollar = "$"

@State private var currency = SettingsView.dollar
@AppStorage("cur") var cur = SettingsView.dollar
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't save the currency in the picker in AppStorage. Do you know, how I do that? Thanks!!

Comment: That is a different question. Please post that separately.